# Changing array to publish API data instead

Tags: arrays, angular, api

I am teaching myself angular and I have built myself a simple shopping cart. it currently has an array with three sample data in although I have created a simple API. I built a quick button to display the API and to  make sure the data request is working but I am having a hard time getting my API data to replace the array data. the link has the code for my full project instead of spamming a lot of code inside this question. if anyone has any advice or ideas it would be greatly appreciated.

many thanks

Comment: (1). Please don't only the external links in the question. (2). The link you've provided shows only the app, not the source code.

Comment: my mistake, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use subscribe

```
 getProducts() {
    this.products = this.http.get<Product[]>(this.ROOT_URL).subscribe(result=>{
      this.productList=result
    })
  }
```

and call this function in  `constructor`